# UIScrollView offsetting content in contentView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am having a very frustrating issue. I know there are all kinds of issues with UIScrollView in iOS7 and XCode 5. I need to implement a scrollview and there are all kinds of tutorials showing you how to do it by switching off auto layout but that then messes with the rest of the views in my app.

I tried the fix of putting my subviews into a container UIView and placing that in the UIScrollView and setting the scrollview's content size to the size of the contained UIVIew. That didn't work. Now I am working with placing everything in the scrollview and it all works with one exception. When I load the view on the simulator or a device the content view is moved down but somewhere around 60 points or so. See image below.

[image]

That white space below the title bar on the right is still the scroll view as I can press and drag within it. Adjusting the contentOffset doesn't do any good as that just scrolls the view down slightly. I have no idea what to do here.

Just a little more info: I setup the scrollview and all the subviews in storyboard and the connected them up. Not sure if that has any bearing on it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think your Scrollview top space constraint have 64 pixels. That's a problem. So, set your top space constraint value to 0

Comment: That worked! Can you repost it as an answer so I can select it as the correct one? Also one more thing I noticed is that my contentSize isn't getting set at first. When I select another tab and then go back it gets set properly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Scrollview top space constraint have 64 pixels. That's a problem. So, set your top space constraint value to 0.

You need to add the constraints before view displayed then contentsize will be set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check UIScrollView's autoresizing mask. It has to be set like this.

[image]